# Laravel Isn't Returning the Edit View

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7, and I created a view for editing users inside views/admin/users/edit.blade.php.

**AdminUsersController**

[image]

**Edit button**

[image]

**index.blade.php**

[image]

When I click on the edit button, it returns the page not found with "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found." text and the URL is: `admin/users/edit/1`

Please, any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Kindly please post your code here(No screen shoot). `AdminUsersController`,`index.blade.php`, and post your  `web routes` so we can have an idea otherwise it's hard to predict what's happening.

Comment: Show us your `php artisan route:list` output.

Comment: You are using `$roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->getall();` and I think this is the line Laravel crashes because there is not method `getall()` on a collection. 

Change it to `$roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->all();`.

Comment: You could check where is your exact mistake by trying `print_r` or `dd()` or `echo`
This should be the first step you should remember to find where is your exact problem.
Here try `echo 'zz'; exit();` on the first line of edit function. If it returns `zz` you are all good till there, otherwise, check your route. Now, keep moving that line downward until you encountered the error. Find, which line is the main culprit. Try fixing that and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the edit route is actually registered in your `routes/web.php` file.

Alternatively, check that the model you're looking at actually exists. If you put your app into debug mode and try again you'll see if Laravel thinks the route doesn't exist, or it simply can't load the model you're calling `findOrFail` on.